# ORACLE SQL: Combining 2 rows of 2 separate select queries

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, union-all

Hello I am very new to SQL and I have an issue.  I have 3 tables job, revenue and cost.  job.unid = cost.job_unid and revenue.job_unid

I want to find the total revenue and cost for each job and then find the profit for each job all on one row:

*The headers looking something like this:*
Job No, Total Revenue, Total Cost, P&L (Rev-Cost)

I tried to make a single query, but after searching on the internet for solutions it seemed like i should query Revenue and Cost seperately and then combine using Union All.

Now I am doing this:

```
  select m,
rlc,
rvatlc,
rtotlc,
clc,
cvatlc,
ctotlc
from(

(select decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m,

sum(nvl(r.amtlc,0)) rlc,
sum(nvl(r.vatamtlc,0)) rvatlc,
sum(nvl(r.amtlc,0))+sum(nvl(r.vatamtlc,0)) rtotlc,
0 clc,
0 cvatlc,
0 ctotlc


from 
job j
full join revenue r on j.unid=r.job_unid
where j.voidby is  null and decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)='SHSEM00131'
group by decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)
)







union all




(select decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m,


0 rlc,
0 rvatlc,
0 rtotlc,
sum(nvl(c.amtlc,0)) clc,
sum(nvl(c.vatamtlc,0)) cvatlc,
sum(nvl(c.amtlc,0))+sum(nvl(c.vatamtlc,0)) ctotlc


from 
job j, cost c 
where j.voidby is  null and j.unid=c.job_unid and decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)='SHSEM00131'
group by decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)
))
```

The result is:
*I am not sure if you can see but it is 2 lines:
1 is the revenue and 1 is  the cost.

I want to combine these 2 lines*

[query result jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NnNO.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: sorry not sure if you saw the query result jpg at the bottom of the post.  I  want to get sum of r.amtlc and r.vatlc and sum of c.amtlc and c.vatlc all on one line with one job number (m)

Comment: from the query result jpg.  I just want that same information consolidated to 1 line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
   select m,
    sum(rlc),
    sum(rvatlc),
    sum(rtotlc),
    sum(clc),
    sum(cvatlc),
    sum(ctotlc)
    from(

    (select decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m,

    sum(nvl(r.amtlc,0)) rlc,
    sum(nvl(r.vatamtlc,0)) rvatlc,
    sum(nvl(r.amtlc,0))+sum(nvl(r.vatamtlc,0)) rtotlc,
    0 clc,
    0 cvatlc,
    0 ctotlc


from 
job j
full join revenue r on j.unid=r.job_unid
where j.voidby is  null and decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)='SHSEM00131'
group by decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)
)

union all

(select decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m,


0 rlc,
0 rvatlc,
0 rtotlc,
sum(nvl(c.amtlc,0)) clc,
sum(nvl(c.vatamtlc,0)) cvatlc,
sum(nvl(c.amtlc,0))+sum(nvl(c.vatamtlc,0)) ctotlc


from 
job j, cost c 
where j.voidby is  null and j.unid=c.job_unid and decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)='SHSEM00131'
group by decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)
)) group by m;
```